# How to display Unicode correctly?

Tags: json, google-maps

I'm wondering how to get WordPress to display these Unicode place names correctly?

I use Google Maps API JSON data to get the place names and create Woocommerce categories for products. However, for some places, the results look like this:

[image: screenshot of front end]

The raw JSON from the API also contains the same characters e.g. `\u0130stanbul`. I've confirmed `u0130` is a Unicode character.

Here's the JSON from Google that was used to create the example:

```
{
  "3": {
    "long_name": "Asia",
    "short_name": "Asia",
    "types": ["continent", "political"]
  },
  "2": {
    "long_name": "Turkey",
    "short_name": "TR",
    "types": ["country", "political"]
  },
  "1": {
    "long_name": "\u0130stanbul",
    "short_name": "\u0130stanbul",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
  },
  "0": {
    "long_name": "Istanbul",
    "short_name": "Istanbul",
    "types": ["locality", "political"]
  }
}
```

Interested to know if anyone has come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you are using a plugin, or you are coding it yourself. Either way, you can use server side or client side to decode or encode your content.

PHP offers the [`utf8_decode();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) and [`utf8_encode();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) functions, that can be used to decode or encode your content before sending it to the browser, or after being received by the server.

If you need to do this on the client side, JavaScript also offers the same functions. You could take a look into [`decodeURIComponent();`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) function.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I should have said, i'm using a custom script to read the JSON into Wordpress and create products and categories. I've checked wp_terms and it has entries like 'u0130zmir' so it sounds like I need to decode it before displaying it in the UI?

Comment: You're welcome. If it's on the server then yes. But since I'm not familiar with your plugin or script, I can't provide an accurate answer. However the plugin might be using a filter before outputting the data, which you can use to do the decoding.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll check this and update the answer :)